# Why doesn't CUDA allow us to use all of the SM memory as L1 cache?

Tags: cuda, cpu-cache

In a CUDA device, each SM has 64KB of **on-chip memory** that is placed close to it. By default, this is partitioned into 48KB of **shared memory** and 16KB of **L1 cache**. For kernels whose memory access pattern is hard to determine, this partitioning can be changed to 16KB of shared memory and 48KB of L1 cache.

Why doesn't CUDA allow *all* of the 64KB per-SM on-chip memory to be used as *L1 cache*?

There are many kinds of kernels which have no use for shared memory, but could use that extra 16KB of L1 cache.

Comment: Just pure speculation, but maybe the way this is implemented is that there are two two separate blocks of RAM, one 48KiB and one 16KiB. And that the configuration just switches which logic is connected to which block.

Comment: Even though you don't use shared memory, some of it used to store data passed as arguments. You can see it as `smem` if you use `--ptxas-options=-v`.

Comment: @Jay that is only true for pre-fermi architectures.

Comment: @Pavan is correct, on Fermi and later, arguments are passed via constant memory.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the reason for this is Computer Graphics.  When running OpenGL or Direct3D code, the SM uses the direct-mapped memory (CUDA shared) for one purpose (e.g. vertex attributes), and the set-associative memory (L1 cache) for another.  For the graphics pipeline, the architects are able to tune specifically how much memory they need for things like vertex attributes based on the vertex throughput limits of other units (for example).

When thinking about architectural decisions for GPUs (and processor design in general, for that matter), it's important to remember that many decisions are largely economic. GPU Computing has a day job: games and graphics.  If it weren't for this day job, GPU computing would not have become economically viable, and massively parallel computing would not likely have become available to the masses.

Nearly every feature of the GPU for computing is used in some way in the graphics pipeline.  If it is not (think ECC memory), then it must be financed with higher product prices for the markets that use it (think HPC).

Comment: Does the Tesla line have a day job too ? I don't know if you can utilize the entire 64k for L1 cache on a Tesla, but Tesla's are not sold as gaming or graphics cards, so wouldn't it be nice to just add that swtich just for Teslas ?

Comment: The Tesla's day job *is* GeForce and Quadro. The GPUs are effectively the same between Tesla and high-end GeForce and Quadro.